# glutCreateWindow - X Error of failed request

Tags: opengl, freeglut

I recently began studying computer graphics programming by way of Jason L. McKesson's free online resource, *Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming*, source:(http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/). Along with the reading material is the source code for the tutorials that are discussed, source:(https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads). After some tweaking, I have been able to successfully build the source code. However, when I try to run any of the tutorials, I am presented with the following error:

```
X Error of failed request: BadRequest(invalid request code or no such operation)
    Major opcode of failed requests: 154(GLX)
    Minor opcode of failed requests: 34()
    Serial number of failed requests: 34
    Current serial number in output stream: 33
```

The error originates within the main function. More precisely, when glCreateWindow() is called:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
    unsigned int displayMode = GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL;
    displayMode = defaults(displayMode, width, height);

    glutInitDisplayMode (displayMode);
    glutInitContextVersion (3, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_DEBUG);
    #endif
    glutInitWindowSize (width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition (300, 200);

    ///RUNTIME ERROR OCCURS BETWEEN HERE!
    int window = glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    /// AND HERE!

    glload::LoadFunctions();

    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);

    if(!glload::IsVersionGEQ(3, 3))
    {
        printf("Your OpenGL version is %i, %i. You must have at least OpenGL 3.3 to run this tutorial.\n",
        glload::GetMajorVersion(), glload::GetMinorVersion());
        glutDestroyWindow(window);
        return 0;
    }

    if(glext_ARB_debug_output)
    {
        glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
        glDebugMessageCallbackARB(DebugFunc, (void*)15);
    }

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if it is relevant, but I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and my graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce 540M. I am new to OpenGL and GLUT, so I have no idea how to resolve this issue; any advice regarding potential solutions would be appreciated.

[EDIT]
As requested, here is the output from glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
GLX_INTEL_swap_event
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.4
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture, 
GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, GL_EXT_texture, 
GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_ARB_point_parameters, 
GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, 
GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, 
GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, 
GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, 
GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, 
GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, 
GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_MESA_texture_array, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, 
GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_EXT_transform_feedback

32 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x022 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x09f 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ab 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ac 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ad 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x060 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

48 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x061  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x063  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x064  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x065  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x066  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x067 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x068 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x069 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x075 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x079  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x087 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x089 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08d 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
```

Comment: What does  **`glxinfo | grep direct`**  tell you?

Comment: Actually, please show the complete output of `glxinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.4
                       ^^^
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

Welp.

Creating a 3.3 Core context with your GL implementation won't work.  It simply isn't supported.

Sounds like you have an Optimus setup so you [might be able to get that working](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics) and use your NVidia GPU instead.

Comment: I was following the installation instructions from the link, but I noticed that the packages it was asking me to install would also remove a substantial amount of other packages, as well as some application programs. I was hoping to get some more information on what I am doing, lest I change something that I cannot revert. I apologize if this whole thing is trivial, but look at it from my perspective: I have no idea what HybridGraphics is.